# How do I chroot a user in proftpd?

Tags: centos, ftp, vps, proftpd

I installed proftpd 1.3.4e successfully. I have compiled it, and did the `make install` part but I want to configure it, don't know how to do so. I want when logged in to be in

```
/var/www/html/
```

I followed this tutorial:

http://www.webune.com/forums/how-to-install-proftpd-linux-centos.html

I have centos 5. Would anyone tell me how to configure it, to be working properly so I can connect using an ftp client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [DefaultRoot](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html) configuration parameter. With that you can modify the directory to which the user is restricted.

You have two options:

- Set DefaultRoot to the homedir and create/modify an user so that it's home-directory is `/var/www/html/`
- Set DefaultRoot to `/var/www/html/`

Comment: thx sir i solved it